# Webservice for bing map to get driving distance using python

Tags: python, web-services, bing-maps

I want to calculate the distance of multiple destination from a single point. How can i calculate this.

Example Url :

```
http://www.hilton.com/search/gi/us/ny/stony_brook/0/00000000000/0/0/0/0/50?wt.srch=1
```

For Example :

I have location(latitude and longitude lets say stony brook) points of hotels in a city and i want to find out the distance of each hotels from my search location(here stony) in a single web service request. let suppose i have 50 hotels locations and want to find the distance of each hotels
from my url location(here stony_brook).I'm looking for a free web service for this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well... Have you written anything yet? Can you show us some of your code you're having trouble with?

Comment: @@Bono:  I edited my post. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on the routing service and tips on using it in .NET here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

Now, this could potentially generate a ton of requests if you make a request for each destination. TO optimize this you can create a function that takes in all the locations you need to calculate distances to and then optimize the calculation by merging locations into a single multi-point route. Bing Maps allows up to 25 locations to be specified in a single route request. If you need distances from A to B, C, D you could calculate a route from A-B-A-C-A-D. The response would return a route leg for each two locations. The odd indexed route legs would be your distance from A to the other locations. This would allow you to merge up to 12 locations into a single request. This would make things much faster and also reduce the number of requests/transactions you make which would also reduce the licensing costs that would be involved.